# Regulating high voltage high current ac supply

Tags: high-voltage, rectifier, high-power

I am trying regulate ~250 ac to have regulated 400v 5A dc.

I have a variac and also a step up transformer (1:5). I know for this type of high voltages full bridge SMPS are used. But actually I don't have time to design one.

So is it possible to achieve this with normal rectifier topology with huge capacitors and high voltage-current diodes, maybe with the help of an inductor to help capacitors?

One main purpose to use a variac is that, I only need stay at 400v and 5A for 1 second. (rising 0 to 400v should take 3 seconds)
Load is 80ohm

Comment: If your load is 50 ohms then you need more current than you think. You also need to specify your voltage tolerance requirements. And give us the specifications for the transformer and variac.

Comment: Definitely need to do that I = V / R sum again. More importantly, what you are aiming at is essentially a pulsed power circuit delivering 3.2 kW; that is a very dangerous and hi-tech toy. The fact that you are asking such a basic question with an even more basic mistake in it strongly suggests that to continue will lead to trouble. I speak as a time-served EMP test engineer. Just don't.

Comment: @GuyInchbald actually I heard this type of warnings a lot. You don't even suggest me something. "Just don't...". Okey a simple mistake I am editing the question for you to be happy. I can't beleive that you are thinking that I don't know V=I/R. 
I know it is basic question but since it is high voltage I need every information that I can get. Maybe I can learn something I don't know. 
I am asking this question to learn more about this and if someone built it before they might suggest me some ideas. Your comment is nothing but an insult.

Comment: @Ismail Seriously, I have been there, I have seen more experienced colleagues than you kill or maim themselves. Even if you choose to be offended, others reading this may be forewarned.

Comment: It is just funny. I think you should read again what you wrote. It includes nothing but "don't do this". This is nothing but discouraging. Who can learn something from it? I could say something like that and it would be the same as your statement: Oh you are calculating wrong and because of that (BTW I know a lot) you are going to kill yourself if you continue. Just stop and quit your job.I don't know who killed himself but it is all about taking precautions. If you take them it is not likely to kill yourself. You might advice about precautions if you know that much and want to forewarn people

Comment: How closely regulated do you need the output to be and what level of ripple is tolerable ?

Comment: @GrahamStevenson 20V ripple is tolerable.

Answer (score 2):

'Normal rectifiers' are indeed available at such voltages. You'll actually need to use 'fast' rectifiers in an SMPS though.

You appear to be talking of a line frequency power supply though. No problem really. Just ensure your transformer is suitably rated. For 2kW DC load, you should typically use a 3,6kVA transformer for safety (not overheating due to harmonics/conduction period related issues). Also the same for the variac. How tightly regulated does the 400V need to be ? That'll be the issue. Do you need help with the ripple calculations, esp voltage ?

Why would you need *huge* capacitors ? Energy storage at high voltages makes better use of CV  product (which relates to capacitor size) than at lower voltages. Energy stored = 1/2.C.V^2 , meaning that storage caps are 10 times more effective volumetrically than at 40V for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. And thanks I will calculate ripple etc. I will try it. I think In short time it is the best way to do it. (transformer and variac I have both rated for 5kW)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just use a bridge rectifier and a filter to make an adjustable DC supply, however it will not be regulated. High current 20-40A bridge rectifiers rated at 600-1000V are cheap and plentiful. The capacitor is another matter.

For example, if your current is 10A and 5Vp-p ripple is acceptable you would need about 20,000uF for a simple filter. That much capacitance at 450V rating would probably run you a couple hundred USD unless you got lucky with a surplus purchase.

Also, keep in mind that variacs don’t like high wiper current so it’s ill-advised to slam the voltage on the capacitor/rectifier. Slow increase is okay.

Comment: How do you arrive at 20,000 uF ?

Comment: @GrahamStevenson C ~= (1/(2*fmains))*I/Vripple. Derivation is straightforward.

Comment: I make the ripple voltage ~1.5V pk-pk based on that figure using my own method.    DeltaV = IL.tnon-conducting/Cstorage  = 5x6,3.10^-3/20.10^-3  = 1.575 (using 60Hz & FW rectification)